# Why we need to import with `import module = require("module")` when we export with `export =`

Tags: javascript, typescript, module

In the [typescript documentation for modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), there is a paragraph that says:

> When exporting a module using `export =`, TypeScript-specific `import module = require("module")` must be used to import the module.

But it does not explain the reason why that is needed, so if anyone knows about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the previous [paragraphs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require)

> Both CommonJS and AMD generally have the concept of an exports object which contains all exports from a module.
>
> They also support replacing the exports object with a custom single object. Default exports are meant to act as a replacement for this behavior; however, the two are incompatible. TypeScript supports export = to model the traditional CommonJS and AMD workflow.
>
> The export = syntax specifies a single object that is exported from the module. This can be a class, interface, namespace, function, or enum.
>
> When exporting a module using export =, TypeScript-specific import module = require("module") must be used to import the module.

Especially:

> TypeScript supports export = to model the traditional CommonJS and AMD workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are sitting in your room and you 1decided to go and eat an Apple, that Apple is mostly going to be in the kitchen, so you first need to go to the kitchen to grab that Apple and then eat it.
It's the same thing with programming languages when you have something(function, class, etc) outside the current file you first need to tell the language that you are trying to access some code that is located in another file.
Hope I could help.